# How to start ASP.net 4.0 app on server that has only ASP.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible? (without installing asp.net 4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible without having ASP.net 4.0 on the server unless you rebuild your app for ASP.net 2.0.

Comment: And how can I rebuild it? (i know how to build rebuild something but how to change these settings) It's ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

Comment: ASP.net 2.0 does not run MVC 3. I think you are stuck either asking your hosting provider to install / enable ASP.net 4.0 or you need to find another hosting provider that supports it.

Comment: ASP.net 3.5 could run MVC 3. But obviously, I have to install 4.o

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible if there is no 4.0 framework installed. Ask your provider to change it to .net 4.0 if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible

You should install .net 4.0

app written in .net 2 will work on .net 4 but the reverse is not possible